# Custom DialogPreference in Android

Tags: java, android

In My Project I am using `SeekBarPreference`. I take reference from http://android.hlidskialf.com/blog/code/android-seekbar-preference code work perfect without any error but when i fetch share Preference value in other activity. then i always found 0 why?
I use below code for get share Preference value:-

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
 String str=Integer.toString( prefs.getInt("duration", 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Shared preferences code for get and put the values below:

code for put the values into sharedpreferences:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Prefs";
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();  
editor.putInt("no", 11);
editor.commit();
```

Code for get the values from sharedpreferences:

```
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);   

    String in=Integer.toString(settings.getInt("no", 0));
```